# Python benchmark tool like nosetests?

Tags: python, testing, benchmarking, nosetests

#### What I want

I would like to create a set of benchmarks for my Python project.  I would like to see the performance of these benchmarks change as I introduce new code.  I would like to do this in the same way that I test Python, by running the utility command like `nosetests` and getting a nicely formatted readout.

#### What I like about `nosetests`

The `nosetests` tool works by searching through my directory structure for any functions named `test_foo.py` and runs all functions `test_bar()` contained within.  It runs all of those functions and prints out whether or not they raised an exception.

I'd like something similar that searched for all files `bench_foo.py` and ran all contained functions `bench_bar()` and reported their runtimes.

#### Questions

Does such a tool exist?

If not what are some good starting points?   Is some of the `nose` source appropriate for this?

Comment: I don't know of any existing tool which will search all your packages for `bench_XXX` as stipulated, but I regularly use `nosetests --with-profile` to get a sense for what's performing well or poorly.

Answer (score 4):

`nosetests` can run any type of test, so you can decide if they test functionality, input/output validity etc., or performance or profiling (or anything else you'd like). [The Python Profiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) is a great tool, and it comes with your Python installation.

```
import unittest
import cProfile

class ProfileTest(unittest.TestCase):
    test_run_profiler:
        cProfile.run('foo(bar)')
        cProfile.run('baz(bar)')
```

You just add a line to the test, or add a test to the test case for all the calls you want to profile, and your main source is not polluted with test code.

If you only want to time execution and not all the profiling information, [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is another useful tool.

Answer (score 3):

The [wheezy](http://pythonhosted.org/wheezy.web/examples.html) documentation has a good example on how to do this with [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/). The important part if you just want to have the timings is to use options `-q` for quiet run, `-s` for not capturing the output (so you will see the output of the report) and `-m benchmark` to only run the 'timing' tests.

I recommend using [py.test](http://pytest.org/) for testing over. To run the example from `wheezy` with that, change the name of the `runTest` method to `test_bench_run` and run only this benchmark with:

```
py.test -qs -k test_bench benchmark_hello.py
```

(`-q` and `-s` having the same effect as with nose and `-k` to select the pattern of the test names).

If you put your benchmark tests in file in a separate file or directory from normal tests they are of course more easy to select and don't need special names.